# Working with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date

I am trying to use simple date format to format the current time:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
    Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    try {
        java.util.Date formattedDate = sdf.parse(now.toString());
        System.out.println(formattedDate.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However the output I am getting is:

```
Fri Oct 18 00:00:00 CDT 2013
```

I am trying to achieve:

```
2013/08/18
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing your `Date` but not formatting it with your `SimpleDateFormat`. **The `Date#toString()` method has its own output format.** Use your `SimpleDateFormat` instead.

```
System.out.println(sdf.format(formattedDate));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [SimpleDateFormat#format(Date date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) method, which returns the date formatted in the desired way. Note that this method is inherited from `DateFormat`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
String formattedDate = sdf.format(now);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to call `parse`
2. You don't need try/catch

Try this much simpler code:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
String formattedDate = sdf.format(new Date());
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this

```
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Locale;

    public class DateFormatTest {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
      Date now = new Date();

      // Use Date.toString()
      System.out.println(now);

      // Use DateFormat
      DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getInstance(); // Date and time
      String dateStr = formatter.format(now);
      System.out.println(dateStr);
      formatter = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();        // time only
      System.out.println(formatter.format(now));

      // Use locale
      formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL,       Locale.FRANCE);
      System.out.println(formatter.format(now));

     // Use SimpleDateFormat
     SimpleDateFormat simpleFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
     System.out.println(simpleFormatter.format(now));
  }
}
```